# Creating records in several tables with a single mutation

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql

I'm studying nodejs w/ graphql and I would like to make sure I'm going in the right direction here.

My study project is based on a simple ERP with entries, products, orders and users.

I have one mutation that creates products indiviadually but I thought that allowing add products while creating a new entry (same mutation and same query as well) was a good aproach but now the code seems weird.

It's all working fine but I would like to have a code very well organized that follows the most common aproaches and best practices.

entry.graphql:

```
type EntryItems {
    id:ID!
    quantity: Int
    created_at: DateTime
    modified_at: DateTime
    Entry:Entry
    Product:Product
  }
  type Entry {
    id:ID!
    User: User
    total: Float
    created_at: DateTime
    modified_at: DateTime
    items:[EntryItems]
  }
  input EntryInput {
    total: Float
    user_id:Int
    items:[EntryItemsInput!]!
  }
 input EntryItemsInput {
    id:ID
    quantity: Int
    Product:ProductInput!
  }
  type Query {
    entries: [Entry]
    entry(id: ID!): Entry!
  }
  type Mutation {
    addEntry(Entry: EntryInput): Entry!
    updateEntry(id: ID!, Entry: EntryInput): updateEntryResposta!
    deleteEntry(id: ID!): deleteEntryResposta!
  }
```

datasource:

````
  async addEntry (Entry) {
    const Entry_id = await this.db
      .insert({
        user_id: Entry.user_id,
        total: Entry.total,
        created_at: new Date(),
        modified_at: new Date()
      })
      .into('entry_details')
    const Items = Entry.items ?? []
    Items.map(async item => {
      if (item.Product.id) {
        this.addEntryItem({
          product_id: item.Product.id,
          quantity: item.quantity,
          entry_id: Entry_id
        })
      } else {
        const new_product = await this.context.dataSources.ProductsAPI.addProduct(
          item.Product
        )
        this.addEntryItem({
          product_id: new_product.id,
          quantity: item.quantity,
          entry_id: Entry_id
        })
      }
    })
    return await this.getEntry(Entry_id)
  }
  async addEntryItem (EntryItem) {
    const Entry_id = await this.db
      .insert(EntryItem)
      .returning('id')
      .into('entry_items')
    return {
      ...EntryItem,
      id: Entry_id
    }
  }
```
````

Comment: This part of your question is a design issue : `I decided to allow creating products while creating a new entry (same mutation and same query as well)` not a code review issue. What I can tell you is that sometimes a customer will ask for this specific feature, and then yes you include it. I don't know node.js so I can review the code.